# Disconnected meteor application

Tags: meteor, local-storage

I am interested in creating an application using the the `Meteor` framework that will be disconnected from the network for long periods of time (multiple hours). I believe meteor stores local data in RAM in a mini-mongodb `js` structure. If the user closes the browser, or refreshes the page, all local changes are lost. It would be nice if local changes were persisted to disk (`localStorage`? `indexedDB`?). Any chance that's coming soon for Meteor?

Related question... how does Meteor deal with document conflicts? In other words, if 2 users edit the same MongoDB JSON doc, how is that conflict resolved? Optimistic locking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conflict resolution is "last writer wins".

More specifically, each MongoDB insert/update/remove operation on a client maps to an RPC.  RPCs from a given client always play back in order.  RPCs from different clients are interleaved on the server without any particular ordering guarantee.

If a client tries to issue RPCs while disconnected, those RPCs queue up until the client reconnects, and then play back to the server in order.  When multiple clients are executing offline RPCs, the order they finally run on the server is highly dependent on exactly when each client reconnects.

For some offline mutations like MongoDB's `$inc` and `$addToSet`, this model works pretty well as is.  But many common modifiers like `$set` won't behave very well across long disconnects, because the mutation will likely conflict with intervening changes from other clients.

So building "offline" apps is more than persisting the local database.  You also need to define RPCs that implement some type of conflict resolution.  Eventually we hope to have turnkey packages that implement various resolution schemes.

Comment: If meteor can add OT as a bundle (eg. sharejs), then conflicts may be resolved in a better way.

Comment: I appreciate the answer to the 2nd part.. How about a use case for a tablet app for name/email collection at an expo with no/poor wireless ? In which case it's only inserts to a collection ? How would one persist to local storage, or would one even need to ?